# Android Java - Webview stays blank

Tags: java, android, android-webview

i am making an app that contains some webview. But somehow they won't load or stay blank or what ever. I can't figure it out.

here is one of my activity's (all are the same)

```
package appkwekerij.gsr;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by ralphneeleman on 10-01-17.
 */

public class LwebActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
NavigationView navigation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lweb);

    WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }
    });
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.leerlingen.gsr.nl");

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_Home) {
        findViewById(R.id.home).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.lweb).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.roosterw).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.poll).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.staffportal).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.parentportal).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.mail).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.WRTS).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.quizlet).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.ov).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.twitter).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.facebook).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.contact).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.feedback).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_Lweb) {
        findViewById(R.id.home).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.lweb).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.roosterw).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.poll).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.staffportal).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.parentportal).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.mail).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.WRTS).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.quizlet).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.ov).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.twitter).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.facebook).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.contact).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.feedback).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_Roosterw) {
        findViewById(R.id.home).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.lweb).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.roosterw).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.poll).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.staffportal).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.parentportal).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.mail).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.WRTS).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.quizlet).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.ov).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.twitter).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.facebook).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.contact).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.feedback).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_Poll) {
        findViewById(R.id.home).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.lweb).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.roosterw).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.poll).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.staffportal).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.parentportal).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.mail).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.WRTS).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.quizlet).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.ov).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.twitter).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.facebook).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.contact).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.feedback).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_Staffportal) {
        findViewById(R.id.home).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.lweb).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.roosterw).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.poll).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.staffportal).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.parentportal).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.mail).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.WRTS).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.quizlet).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.ov).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.twitter).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.facebook).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.contact).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.feedback).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_Parentportal) {
        findViewById(R.id.home).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.lweb).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.roosterw).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.poll).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.staffportal).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.parentportal).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.mail).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.WRTS).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.quizlet).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.ov).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.twitter).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.facebook).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.contact).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.feedback).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_Mail) {
        findViewById(R.id.home).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.lweb).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.roosterw).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.poll).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.staffportal).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.parentportal).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.mail).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.WRTS).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.quizlet).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.ov).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.twitter).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.facebook).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.contact).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.feedback).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_WRTS) {
        findViewById(R.id.home).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.lweb).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.roosterw).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.poll).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.staffportal).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.parentportal).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.mail).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.WRTS).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.quizlet).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.ov).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.twitter).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.facebook).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.contact).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.feedback).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_Quizlet) {
        findViewById(R.id.home).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.lweb).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.roosterw).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.poll).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.staffportal).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.parentportal).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.mail).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.WRTS).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.quizlet).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.ov).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.twitter).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.facebook).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.contact).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.feedback).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_OV) {
        findViewById(R.id.home).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.lweb).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.roosterw).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.poll).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.staffportal).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.parentportal).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.mail).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.WRTS).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.quizlet).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.ov).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.twitter).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.facebook).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.contact).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.feedback).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_Twitter) {
        findViewById(R.id.home).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.lweb).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.roosterw).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.poll).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.staffportal).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.parentportal).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.mail).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.WRTS).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.quizlet).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.ov).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.twitter).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.facebook).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.contact).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.feedback).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_Facebook) {
        findViewById(R.id.home).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.lweb).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.roosterw).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.poll).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.staffportal).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.parentportal).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.mail).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.WRTS).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.quizlet).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.ov).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.twitter).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.facebook).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.contact).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.feedback).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_Contact) {
        findViewById(R.id.home).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.lweb).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.roosterw).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.poll).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.staffportal).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.parentportal).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.mail).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.WRTS).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.quizlet).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.ov).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.twitter).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.facebook).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.contact).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.feedback).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_Feedback) {
        findViewById(R.id.home).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.lweb).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.roosterw).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.poll).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.staffportal).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.parentportal).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.mail).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.WRTS).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.quizlet).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.ov).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.twitter).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.facebook).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.contact).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.feedback).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
    }
}
```

Android manifest:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="appkwekerij.gsr">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="GSR"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

And my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

i've been trying to look for answers on google or stackoverflow but i can't seem getting it to work...

any help is **very much** appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In your code,I can not see that `LwebActivity` registered in `manifest`.
You can check it.

In your layout,I just saw WebView in it.So in your code,you can delete other code and have a try.